# How to set the cursor setting in the space between containers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a calculator app. For that I want the cursor to be a pointer on the buttons and a normal arrow everywhere else. But Once, I make the cursor to be a pointer on the buttons, it remains a pointer in the space between the buttons.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
          title: Text('Calculator'),
          centerTitle: true,
          titleTextStyle:
              TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber[600],
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
              width: 435,
              height: 300,
            ),
            MouseRegion(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue[600],
                width: 435,
                height: 350,
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  children: [
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10) ,
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      onExit: (event) => {},
                    ),
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                    ),
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      
                    ),
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                     
                    ),
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      
                    ),
                    MouseRegion(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      ),
                      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                     
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this as result:
[image]

But the cursor is also being changed in these region marked in green.[image]

I want cursor to be normal arrow in these region not clickable like, in the black region. And systemMouseCursor.text also has no impact.

Answer (score -1):

To change the cursor to the normal arrow in the space between the buttons, you can wrap the GridView.count widget with a GestureDetector widget and set its behavior property to HitTestBehavior.translucent. This allows the GestureDetector to capture the gestures and change the cursor only when the gestures are inside the GridView.count widget.

Here is the modified code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
          title: Text('Calculator'),
          centerTitle: true,
          titleTextStyle:
              TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.amber[600],
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
              width: 435,
              height: 300,
            ),
            MouseRegion(
              child: GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue[600],
                  width: 435,
                  height: 350,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    children: [
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10) ,
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                        onExit: (event) => {},
                      ),
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                      ),
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                        
                      ),
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                       
                      ),
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                        
                      ),
                      MouseRegion(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          height: 10,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        ),
                        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                       
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this modification, the cursor will be a normal arrow in the space between the buttons and a pointer on the buttons.